# Axon framework with Axon Kafka extension

Tags: axon

We are thinking about using CQRS/ES and we want to integrate the Axon framework with Kafka, but the "release condidate" is a problem, have you thought about releasing this extension? As Axon Project Lead, what do you think if we use Spring Cloud Stream instead of this extension?

Answer (score 0):

What would've been easier to contact AxonIQ more directly concerning the [Kafka Extension](https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-kafka), would be to drop a question on our own user forum. We do monitor SO (hence the response), but the timeframes tend to be a bit lower.

Now, to the subject of your question. Of course, we have thought about moving the Kafka Extension out of its release candidate state! It has been in that state though, as it has been pending potential bug responses.

As it stands we do not have a lot of direct client contact with users of the Kafka Extension. Mainly because the majority of users are moving towards [Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server). The benefit of Axon Server is that it does not only do events (like Kafka) but also provide command and query distribution, as well as giving the right level of support for Event Stores. This combination is paramount for your infrastructure to construct a clean CQRS, DDD, and Event Sourcing-based application.

On any note, the fact we didn't have a lot of direct contact with users complicated the process to be confident enough everything works quite some.
It has been in this state for quite some time right now though, and we're looking into releasing it soonish.

> As Axon Project Lead, what do you think if we use Spring Cloud Stream instead of this extension?

Spring Cloud Streams sounds like a fine event distribution platform, just as Kafka. You are ending up with the same predicament I just highlighted on. It only solves event distribution, whereas you also need command and query distribution, and a dedicated event store. If you want to stay focused on your business functionality instead of setting up four different types infra, I would recommend you give Axon Server a try.

Comment: By the way, if you are using it Jalel, it would b great if you could provide some feedback actually. On Axon's forum, there's a dedicated topic to discuss these matters. The topic in question can be found here:https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/are-you-using-axons-kafka-extension/3428